# No named parameter with the name error in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, debugging, flutter-layout, flutter-test

When I run my flutter application on android studio this error appear, I did flutter clean and many commands but it didn't work.

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
/E:/setupfolder/programs/AndroidSDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pull_to_refresh-1.6.4/lib/src/smart_refresher.dart:434:9: Error: No named parameter with the name 'keyboardDismissBehavior'.
        keyboardDismissBehavior:
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/E:/setupfolder/programs/AndroidSDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scroll_view.dart:588:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const CustomScrollView({
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'E:\setupfolder\programs\AndroidSDK\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 904

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'E:\setupfolder\programs\AndroidSDK\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Comment: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrade pull_to_refresh to version 1.6.3
It is not compatible with the latest version of flutter
https://github.com/peng8350/flutter_pulltorefresh/issues/424

Comment: oh my, first attempt with flutter and I'm here on SO... It's very promising

Answer (score 1):

Update the version of `pull_to_refresh` to  `^1.6.4` in pubspec.yaml